# python - Insert Data to SQL Server Table using pymssql (TypeError)

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm trying to insert rows into a table from an array, but an error occurs: TypeError

Here is the code:

```
data = []
connsql = pymssql.connect(server='servername', user='username', 
password='password', database='database')
cursorsql = connsql.cursor()
for i in data:
    tsql = 'insert into ComputerName_IPAddress (ComputerName,IPAddress,TimeStamp) values'
    tsql += "('"+i[0]+"','"+i[1]+"',GETDATE())"
    cursorsql.execute(tsql)
cursorsql.close()
connsql.close()
```

but an error occurs:

```
tsql += "('"+i[0]+"','"+i[1]+"',GETDATE())"
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

array data contains lines:

```
('ZRI-1234', '10.746.60.15')
('ZUZ-1207', '10.716.70.53')
```

How to fix it?

Comment: By "array data contains lines" you mean `data`? What's `len(data)`? What's `len(i)` in the `for` loop?

Comment: There seems to be no space between `values`, the keyword and your data.

Comment: "array data contains lines" - No, it doesn't. Your `data = []` statement ensures that the array is empty.